# Multiple node instances with a single database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, redis

I'm currently writing a Node app and I'm thinking ahead in scaling. As I understand, horizontal scaling is one of the easier ways to scale up an application to handle more concurrent requests. My working copy currently uses MongoDb on the backend.

My question is thus this: I have a data structure that resembles a linked list that requires the order to be strictly maintained. My (imaginary) concern is that when there is a race condition to the database via multiple node instances, it is possible that the resolution of the linked list will be incorrect.

To give an example: Imagine the server having this list a->b. Instance 1 comes in with object c and instance 2 comes in with object d. It is possible that there is a race condition in which both instances read a->b and decides to append their own objects to the list. Instance 1 will then imagine it's insertion to be a->b->c while instance 2 think it's a->b->d when the database actually holds a->b->c->d.

In general, this sounds like a job for optimistic locking, however, as I understand, neither MongoDB or Redis (the other database that I am considering) does transactions in the SQL manner.

I therefore imagine the solution to be one of the below:

1. Implement my own transaction in MongoDB using flags. The client does a findAndModify on the lock variable and if successful, performs the operations. If unsuccessful, the client retries after a certain timeout.
2. Use Redis transactions and pubsub to achieve the same effect. I'm not exactly sure how to do this yet, but it sounds like it might be plausible.
3. Implement some sort of smart load balancing. If multiple clients is operating on the same item, route them to the same instance. Since JS is single threaded, the problem would be solved. Unfortunately, I didn't find a straightforward solution to that.

I sure there exists a better, more elegant way to achieve the above, and I would love to hear any solutions or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: +1 just for using node.js + mongodb

Comment: Also look at neo4j if you data is looking more like a graph than a set of documents...

Comment: You might find [Locking with `SETNX`](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) interesting.

Comment: I might end up with a variation where Redis acts as a working cache and Mongo is used as the final data store. There's nothing inherently wrong with using Redis, but as far as I can tell, to properly represent a document in Redis would require a higher level of abstraction on the code side (basically object to key translations) and queries have to be very deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and the list is being stored as one single document, you might be looking at row versioning. So add a property to the document that will handle the version, when you update, you increase (or change) the version and you make that a conditional update:

//update(condition, value)

update({version: whateverYouReceivedWhenYouDidFind}, newValue)

Hope it helps.
Gus

Answer (score 0):

You want the findAndModify command on mongodb that will guarantee an atomic modification while returning the newly modified doc. As the changes are serial and atomic instance 1 will have a->b->c and instance 2 will have a->b->c->d

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately I'll need to do some processing in between the find and modify commands so it seems like it wouldn't be possible using this mongo API?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is adding new elements to the list, you could use a Redis list and include the time in every value you add. The list may be unsorted on redis but should be quickly sortable when retrieved.